# Does LockMode.WRITE release the Lock if no update is done

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g, locking

Hibernate 3.2.6
Oracle 11.x

The code I am looking at locks a table row for update using this line:

```
Query query = createQuery("from MyTable t where t.col1 = :param1");
            query.setParameter("param1", "blah");
            query.setLockMode("s", LockMode.WRITE);
            return (SysType) query.uniqueResult();
```

The code subsequently does this:

```
getSession().saveOrUpdate(sysType);
getSession().flush();
```

where getSession() returns a Hibernate session.

My question is this - when does the lock get released? If the sysType object has not been updated since it was read, does the DB get called by saveOrUpdate and does the lock get released?

I am looking at an issue with my application and I suspect it is being caused by the row being locked and the lock not being released thereby blocking other reads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pessimistic locks are released at the end of the transaction, regardless of whether the object is updated or not. It is the way the database works; it has nothing to do with Hibernate.

However, don't use [`LockMode.WRITE`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/LockMode.html#WRITE):

> WRITE lock is obtained when an object is updated or inserted. This
>   lock mode is for internal use only and is not a valid mode for load()
>   or lock() (both of which throw exceptions if WRITE is specified).

Use [`LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/LockMode.html#PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) instead if you need pessimistic locks (`select for update` construct).

Comment: "internal use only" - internal to what, to hibernate?

Comment: @CodeClimber Yes, internal to Hibernate.